# SQL to select records from multiple table using joins

Tags: sql, join

I want a SQL select query for below scenario. I have 6 tables.

1) University

- Univ_id
- University_Name

2)College

- College_id
- College_Name
- Univ_id (FK)

3)Department

- Dept_id
- Dept_name
- College_id (FK)

4) Subjects

- Subject_id
- Subject Name

5)Student

- Student_id
- Student_name
- Dept_id (FK)
- Subject_id (FK)

6)Student_Subject

- Student_id (FK)
- Subject_id (FK)
- Marks

I want the sum of marks for per Subject and per University. Please suggest and SQL statement for the same.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried SQL statements using inner joins and since i have very less experience on writing SQL using joins, couldn't progress much.

Comment: It would be better if you could describe where you are stuck. If somebody writes your query for you, you'll be stuck for help again  whenever you need a different query.

Comment: Please read [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Show what parts you can do & explain where you are stuck & what parts you can do. Give a [mcve]. Clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT u.university_name, su.subject_name, sum(ss.marks) sum_of_marks
FROM university u
JOIN college c ON c.univ_id=u.univ_id
JOIN department d ON d.college_id=c.college_id
JOIN student st ON st.dept_id = d.dept_id
JOIN student_subject ss ON ss.student_id=st.student_id
JOIN subjects su ON su.subject_id=ss.subject_id
GROUP BY  u.university_name, su.subject_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Marks per subject:

```
SELECT su.subject_Name,
       sum(ss.marks)
FROM student_subject ss
JOIN subjects su ON ss.subject_id = su.subject_id
GROUP BY su.subject_Name
```

Marks per university:

```
SELECT u.university_name,
       sum(ss.marks)
FROM student_subject ss
JOIN student st ON st.student_id = ss.student_id
JOIN department d ON d.dept_id = st.dept_id
JOIN college c ON c.college_id = d.college_id
JOIN university u ON u.univ_id = c.univ_id
GROUP BY u.university_name
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted a single select statement to get "total marks" per university, per subject.